# Should I need to explictly cast hard-coded values in UNION joins for ints not to end up as strings using mysqlnd?

Tags: mariadb, mysqlnd

Using MariaDB 10.3.9 and given the following query:

`SELECT photoId FROM photos WHERE photoId = 123;`

using PDO and mysqlnd in php `var_dump` will give `int(123)`, as expected.

But if I change the query to

`SELECT photoId FROM photos WHERE photoId = 123
 UNION
 SELECT 1 FROM photos WHERE photoId = 456;`

Then the output becomes `string(3) "123"`, `string(1), "1"`.

If I change the query to

`SELECT photoId FROM photos WHERE photoId = 123
 UNION
 SELECT CAST(1 AS UNSIGNED INT) FROM photos WHERE photoId = 456;`

I correctly get `int(123)`, `int(1)`.

This seems like very strange behaviour - why is MariaDB choosing to cast the explicit 1 to a string, rather than leave it as the integer it's written as?

Weirder still, I have photoId defined as unsigned.  If I just use `CAST(1 AS INT)` it **still** comes through as a string, just because I missed the `UNSIGNED` part.

Answer (score 0):

To MySQL...  If the column `photoId` is `INT` (or any other numeric type), then either of these work equally well:

```
WHERE photoId = 123
WHERE photoId = '123'
WHERE photoId = "123"
```

If the column `photoId` is a `VARCHAR`, then you should do one of these:

```
WHERE photoId = '123'
WHERE photoId = "123"
```

Failure to use quote the string defeats the use of an index, thereby making the query run slow.

PDO will do the 'right thing'.

Don't bother with any CASTing.

My experience says that the *first* `SELECT` in a `UNION` controls the datatype.  So I, too, am surprised by your results.

Comment: The column is of course an int, but I think you may have misread the question.